# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported error message

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, segue

I am working on an app where the user has the possibility to add products and those products are then displayed in a TableView. I created a TableViewController with static cells and two sections and I want to hook the cell in the second section with another TableViewController.

I dragged the TableViewController from the object library, embedded it in a navigation controller and made a push segue from the cell to the NavigationController but when I try to run the app I get the following error message in the output window:

**2013-03-20 09:55:32.981 STAM[725:c07]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
 **First throw call stack:
(0x1d04012 0x11e8e7e 0x22a5b0 0x22a098 0x585da3 0x577ad9 0x577b54 0x1df899 0x1dfb3d 0xbe6e83 0x1cc3376 0x1cc2e06 0x1caaa82 0x1ca9f44 0x1ca9e1b 0x1f3c7e3 0x1f3c668 0x13065c 0x2a6d 0x2995)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception**

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpShv.png) form my storyboard.

Thank you very much!

Granit

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html in short, your `UINavigationController` is at the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip :) i pushed the segue directly to the table view controller without embedding it in the NavigationController and now it works fine. Could you answer the question so i can accept it? Thanks again :) Granit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UINavigationController` is at the wrong place. It should be before the `UITableViewController`.

You can select the `UITableViewController` from story board then from menu: Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.

You can get more info about the navigation stack from the reference guide.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html