# Pushing a navigation controller is not supported in iOS 7.1, but works fine in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, segue

I'm using this code snippet to make a left to right segue:

```
    var src: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
    var dst: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
    var transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    var timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.35
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    src.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    //src.navigationController!.presentViewController(dst, animated: true, completion: {})
    src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
```

But `src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)` when using iOS 7.1 simulator causes 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported' error, but on iOS 8 it works just fine.

When I try to replace this line with `src.navigationController!.presentViewController(dst, animated: true, completion: {})` everything works weird. At first, I can't get proper animation, because it starts to combine default animation with custom. Also after some segues `src.navigationController` becomes `nil` for no reason and code crashes.

So, can i use `src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)` in iOS 7?
Or am I using `src.navigationController!.presentViewController(dst, animated: true, completion: {})` the wrong way, that it leads to navigation controller becoming `nil`?

EDIT:

[image: segues]

SOLVED:
There was a wrong segue from the second view controller to navigation controller, I've deleted it and created a correct one, from the second view controller to the first

Comment: You are trying to push an instance of `UINavigationController` onto a navigation stack - even if it works on iOS8, it does not make any sense.

Comment: @Krumelur But I'm pushing `UIViewController`, not an `UINavigationController`

Comment: Can you post a photo of your storyboard connections if you have any? Is the destinationViewController embedded in a UINavigationController?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525661/pushing-a-navigation-controller-is-not-supported-error-message